# how to convert boolean condition from vb to c#?

Tags: c#, vb.net

I'm using asp.net with c# project,I am merging the vb code into c#
           code.

```
public DataSet GetLabTestsOrdered(long lOrderID,bool includeOrderDetails=false)
               {
                 CStr(IIf(includeOrderDetails,",LO.patientprofileid,LO.doctorid,LO.order_datetime

                ", "")) & _

               }
```

So I want to convert the boolean condition from vb to c#. So, how I can do?

Comment: Please make your code more complete and better to read. I wonder if it even compiles as-is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VB.net

```
IIf(includeOrderDetails,",LO.patientprofileid,LO.doctorid,LO.order_datetime", "")
```

C#.net
Ternary operator

```
includeOrderDetails ? ",LO.patientprofileid,LO.doctorid,LO.order_datetime" : ""
```

CStr part is not required as it already a string.

Comment: Thank you sunil. its working fine.

Comment: `CStr` is also not required in VB.NET if you use the conditional operator `If`

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for ternary operator

```
var result = includeOrderDetails ? ",LO.patientprofileid,LO.doctorid,LO.order_datetime" : ""
```

Answer (score 0):

This actually works *better* in C#. C# has true inline ifs, where the part of the equation that isn't used will never even be evaluated, just like with `ElseIf` in VB.

The full explanation is [here on MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator), but basically, it works like this:

```
myVariable = isConditionTrue ? valueForTrue : valueForFalse;
```

This also retains the parameter type, so unlike with `IIf`, there is no need to cast the result.

Comment: VBnet also has "true" inline if nowadays. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/if-operator

Comment: Interesting. Seems like a bit of a mix of `?` and `??`. Though the explanation there is quite confusing on some points.

Comment: Yeah. It is the same method/operator for two very different tasks. Vbnet: `If(a,b,c)` == Csharp: `a?b:c` and Vbnet: `If(a,b)` == Csharp: `a??b`.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the IIf and remove the CStr and change to:

```
if (includeOrderDetails == true)
                return ",LO.patientprofileid,LO.doctorid,LO.order_datetime";
            else
                return "";
```

Which is the same as the brief:

```
    includeOrderDetails ? "LO.patientprofileid,LO.doctorid,LO.order_datetime" : "";
```